# Import text file in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I'd like to import a text file in Elasticsearch.
The text file contains a single (hash)value per line.
After spending several hours of struggling, I didn't get it done.
Help is greatly appreciated.

Elasticsearch 5.1.2 with Logstash installed.

Sample data:

```
2d75cc1bf8e57872781f9cd04a529256
00f538c3d410822e241486ca061a57ee
3f066dd1f1da052248aed5abc4a0c6a1
781770fda3bd3236d0ab8274577dddde
86b6c59aa48a69e16d3313d982791398
```

Need just one index 'hashes', type 'md5'

Comment: can you show few text inside the line and also please show how you want to model the data in elasticsearch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you have logstash, import it with logstash.

Example config:

```
input {
   file {
      path => "/path/myfile"
      start_position => "beginning"
      type => "md5"
   }
}
output {
   elasticsearch {
       index => "hashes"
   }
}
```

assuming you run logstash on the same instance as elasticsearch.

Comment: Thanks.
I'm running Logstash on the same instance. My config is slightly different then yours.  I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 2):

You can use **[duckimport](https://github.com/ofarukcaki/duckimport)**, it's similar to Logstash but easy to use. I'm the developer of that